# Getting PyCharm warning: Unexpected type(s): (int) Possible type(s): (str) (str) (str)

Tags: python, pycharm

In this below code i am getting warning

```
(Unexpected type(s): (int) Possible type(s): (str) (str) (str) )
```

from PyCharm, even when my code is running properly. I don't know why it is giving me this warning it is very irritating to see that warning message in the code.

```py
stock_data = {'2023-12-29': {'1. open': '255.1000', '2. high': '255.1900'},
               '2023-12-28': {'1. open': '263.6600', '2. high': '265.1300'},
               '2023-12-27': {'1. open': '258.3500', '2. high': '263.3400'},
             }
dates = [item[0] for index, item in enumerate(stock_data.items())] # ⬅️ While indexing [0] it giving me the warning.
print(dates)    # ⬅️ Output: ['2023-12-29', '2023-12-28', '2023-12-27']
```

Comment: Sidenote: you can just iterate over `stock_data.keys()` (or even just `stock_data`) instead of iterating over `stock_data.items()` and only using the first element of the tuple. The `enumerate` also seems unnecessary. In fact, the whole list compressions is just `list(stock_data)`.

Comment: Where do you get this?

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) I guess the linter PyCharm uses thinks you're trying to index one of the strings, it's probably showing the error since you might've typed the `enumerate()` around it later. Try invalidating caches/restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
from typing import Tuple, Dict

stock_data: Dict[str, Dict[str, str]] = {
    '2023-12-29': {'1. open': '255.1000', '2. high': '255.1900'},
    '2023-12-28': {'1. open': '263.6600', '2. high': '265.1300'},
    '2023-12-27': {'1. open': '258.3500', '2. high': '263.3400'},
}

dates = [item[0] for index, item in enumerate(stock_data.items())]  
print(dates)
```

Comment: No, facing same error.

I know how to hide the error using -> # noinspection PyTypeChecker
but i want to know that why am i getting that?